# How to stop Python code execution when some condition is (not) met?

Tags: python, passwords, new-operator

I'm new to Python and I can't figure out how to stop the execution of my Python code when some condition is (not) met. I need to check if the user input (password) matches some string, and if not, and the code execution. Here is my code:

```py
password = input("Welcome To Computer Put In Your Password.")
if password == "12345":
    print("Welcome,Caden")
else:
    print("Wrong Password")
    # I want it to be able to stop the code after it says wrong password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
print("Wrong Password")
```

to

```
raise SystemExit("Wrong Password")
```

Answer (score 1):

`quit()` is what you're looking for.

```
password = input("Welcome To Computer Put In Your Password.")
if password == "12345":
    print("Welcome,Caden")
else:
    print("Wrong Password")
    quit()
```